# How to disable shortcuts in WPF TextBox

Tags: wpf, textbox, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to disable all default shortcuts in WPF TextBox. Shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> etc. Can this be done?. It looks to me that these shortcuts are executed before `KeyDown` event

Comment: Because I'm doing a control which allows user to specify any shortcut he want to use for some action. And of course I don't need to select everything on Ctrl+A, but instead I would just display it

Comment: Ah. I would've expected WPF to provide a control that did something similar already. Thanks for the info.

Comment: The InputBinding's should be updated to use ApplicationCommands.NotACommand to disable them: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.notacommand.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can intercept the keystrokes in the `PreviewKeyDown` event.  Set the `e.Handled` member to `true` and that will prevent the actually processing of the keys.

Comment: Thanks. That's right to the point. Never seen this preview event before

Comment: That'll only work for keystrokes. What if the command is invoked via the context menu? Or the application menu?

Comment: @Kent, I *believe* that goes through WPF commands.  I am very unfamiliar with their implementation and cannot provide any useful comments on how that would work.  Although I'd love to see someone do so.

Comment: @Jared: Your method prevents an input binding from invoking the command, but there are other ways to execute the command. Anyways, it's not exactly clear whether the OP wants to disable the *commands* altogether or just the *keystrokes* to invoke the commands.

Comment: The InputBinding's should be updated to use ApplicationCommands.NotACommand to disable them.

Answer (score 3):

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CommandManager.AddPreviewCanExecuteHandler(_textBox, _canExecute);
}

private void _canExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = false;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

The above will prevent the TextBox from saying it can handle *any* command. You can selectively choose which commands you want to disable by examining the `EventArgs`. Or you can do this in XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="_textBox">
    <TextBox.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" CanExecute="_canExecute"/>
    </TextBox.CommandBindings>
</TextBox>
```

Here we're just disabling the execution of the Copy command. Control-C won't work, nor will the context menu or main menu. In fact, any control that executes the Copy command will be disabled if the focus is in the `TextBox`.